# Why does not nginx close connection right after client FIN received?

Tags: linux, nginx, tcp

**Problem:** 
We have setup a CDN provider as a proxy to our static image file server. After hours we got experiencing critically high amount of TCP SYN drops ratio and abnormal high number of orphaned connections.

**Observations in order to solve the problem:**
I captured 1.5 seconds of the server traffic and checked out some image downloads. 
The suspicious thing is that nginx - which is almost configured with the defaults - is responding to the FIN packet of the CDN server with ACK instead of FIN/ACK. After the ACK from nginx, there is silence for whole a second on the connection port which means the server has nothing further to send. I couldn't capture more than 1.5 seconds due to high traffic.

Here is the summary of a sample TCP connection:

```
No.     Time        Source      Destination Proto   Length and Info 
20      0.004281671 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TCP     74  20200 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=28400 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2822189024 TSecr=0 WS=1024
21      0.004333161 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TCP     74  443 → 20200 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2611883387 TSecr=2822189024 WS=128
372     0.125341624 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TCP     66  20200 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=28672 Len=0 TSval=2822189148 TSecr=2611883387
373     0.125357371 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TLSv1.2 287 Client Hello
374     0.125367976 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TCP     66  443 → 20200 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=222 Win=30080 Len=0 TSval=2611883417 TSecr=2822189149
392     0.127328681 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TLSv1.2 2882    Server Hello, Certificate
393     0.127339623 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TLSv1.2 233 Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
645     0.244326565 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TCP     66  20200 → 443 [ACK] Seq=222 Ack=2984 Win=34816 Len=0 TSval=2822189267 TSecr=2611883418
646     0.244353033 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TLSv1.2 192 Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
647     0.244630520 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TLSv1.2 324 New Session Ticket, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
1121    0.360323576 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TLSv1.2 1496    Application Data    
1122    0.360373767 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TCP     66  443 → 20200 [ACK] Seq=3242 Ack=1778 Win=33024 Len=0 TSval=2611883476 TSecr=2822189383
1123    0.360539425 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TLSv1.2 392 Application Data    
1124    0.360614290 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TLSv1.2 97  Encrypted Alert 
1554    0.477351117 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TCP     78  [TCP Window Update] 20200 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1778 Ack=3242 Win=40960 Len=0 TSval=2822189500 TSecr=2611883447 SLE=3568 SRE=3600
1555    0.477369934 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TCP     66  20200 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1778 Ack=3600 Win=43008 Len=0 TSval=2822189501 TSecr=2611883476
1596    0.505356016 [CDN IP]    [NGINX IP]  TCP     66  20200 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1778 Ack=3600 Win=43008 Len=0 TSval=2822189530 TSecr=2611883476
1597    0.505368886 [NGINX IP]  [CDN IP]    TCP     66  443 → 20200 [ACK] Seq=3600 Ack=1779 Win=33024 Len=0 TSval=2611883512 TSecr=2822189530
```

Also I guess the CDN server uses HTTP keep alive header. My uncertain analysis is that a misconfiguration from the CDN side is making it to use one connection for each image as well as sending keep-alive headers. It makes nginx let the TCP be keep-alive and the FIN packet is simply responded by an ACK. Then a workaround would be to reduce nginx keep-alive timeout to 1 second.

**The Question**: What would be the exact cause of this problem? Or what should I change to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I checked the content of the requests the behavior of nginx was due to CDN's behavior. Because the CDN was using keep alive connections and the duration of keep alive connections in nginx was set to something high like 60s. When I decreased this to 15 seconds the situation backed to normal.

Answer (score 1):

What is the *problem* you are trying to solve?

Orphaned connections and "SYN drops" are not really a problem. NGINX has little, last i looked, care about these details.

you added a CDN. and that CDN is not a *user*. as such it behaves differently.

you may be running out of connection space in the pool. increase that.

please post more specific questions for additional clarity.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. Thank you for your kind answer. Also I was wondering if you rather comment these things instead of posting an answer.

Comment: yes. if i can comment.